# Mensagem de suspensão com "e28"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, suspensão

Eu estava olhando uma resposta no site, e ao acessar o link do usuário, vi que ele estava suspenso:

[image: Esta conta foi temporariamente suspensa. O período de suspensão termina e28 26/01/21 às 14:28.]

Há um erro no texto da suspensão, o que aquele **e28** está fazendo lá no lugar de **em**?

Achei um outro usuário também suspenso, e a mensagem de suspensão lá continha também o texto "para tranquilizar". Neste caso, a mensagem não continha qualquer erro de redação. Assim sendo, isso só acontece em alguns dos usuários suspensos, provavelmente dependendo da razão pela qual se deu a suspensão.

Comment: Posso estar me confundido, mas tenho quase certeza que isto aparece em outro lugar, preciso buscar umas conversas antigas no chat quando mencionei o problema, só que não sei se era e28, mas era parecido (ou variava)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Deve ser o minuto. Provavelmente o "em" está dentro da máscara de formatação ao invés de fora.

Comment: Bem possivel, mas ainda estou com uma sensação de que a falha existe em outro lugar, possivelmente em recompensas, mas faz muito tempo que havia reportado isto a um CM ou moderador, se encontrar trarei pra cá.

Comment: Eu vi outro que estava "*termina e57 11/01/21 às 13:57*", então o "em" deve estar dentro da máscara mesmo... Mas não são todos os casos, eu vi outros que o "em" está correto.

Answer (score 3):

Este problema foi corrigido. Obrigado!